C++ equivalent of 'ros2 params load'
Is there an equivalent rclcpp C++ API call for the command line call 'ros2 params load'? I know there is the 'rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters' services that you can call to set individual parameters but there doesn't seem to be a way to set parameters from a file using the C++ API.
I am running ros2 rolling distro on Ubuntu 24.04.

It is not possible out of the box. However, have a look at this feature request. The discussion contains some suggestions on how to do it, e.g. there is a code example here.

So the example code linked above was for loading the yaml file in the node that we're setting the parameters for. I wanted to do this from a remote node. The thread indicated there was a way to do it from a remote node but I can't see how.

Actually never mind. I saw how you can do this for a remote node as well using the AsyncParametersClient. Thanks for the reference.

Depending on your exact use case, it might also be relevant to have a look at Tomoya Fujita's ros2_persist_parameter_server package.
